# Matsubara frequency summation when residue theorem is suspicious?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, many-body, greens-functions

I need to calculate the bosonic frequency summation
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(z_n-4)^2(z_n+2)^2}\ln\left[1+\frac{(z_n-4)(z_n+2)}{(z_n-5)(z_n+3)}\right],$$ where $z_n=\mathrm{i}\frac{2n\pi}{\beta}$.

There're singularities at $z=5,z=-3$ or the roots $z=1\pm\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}$ of the argument inside $\ln$. The branch cut of $\ln$ prevents us from using residue theorem together with functions like $\frac{1}{\mathrm{exp}{[\beta z]}-1}$ to evaluate the summation.

So this way is wrong at least for this case? I think the summation is not divergent at all. There must be a way to evaluate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this might be more at home on Math.SE

Comment: See the branch cut section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration